# I am working on leave conditions and i want to display the leave types according to gender in odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

The condition is if the employee in *hr.employee* is female then display the leave type which can be allocated only to female employee and same as for the male employee

Gender specific **leave** will be saved from 
***hr_leave_rules.leave_rules***
code provided as follows:

```
class HRLeaveRules(models.Model):
_name = 'hr_leave_rules.leave_rules'

half_day_allowed = fields.Selection([
    ('yes',"Yes"),
    ('no',"No")],
    string="Half Day Allowed", required=True)
gender_specific = fields.Selection([
    ('all' ,"All"),
    ('male',"Male"),
    ('female',"Female")],
    string="Gender Specific", required=True)    
leaves_allowed_on_prorata_basis = fields.Selection([
    ('yes',"Yes"),
    ('no',"No")],
    string="Leaves allowed on pro rata basis", required=True)
leave_encashment = fields.Boolean(string="Leave Encashment", 
    required=True)
leave_encashment_for_maximum = fields.Integer(
    string = "Leave Encashment for maximum", required=True)     
can_emp_club_leave = fields.Selection([
    ('yes',"Yes"),
    ('no',"No")],
    string="Can Employees Club this leave with any other leave", 
    required=True)  
past_dated_leave_allowed = fields.Selection([
    ('yes',"Yes"),
    ('no',"No")],
    string="Past dated leave application allowed", required=True)   
override_paid_leave_to_unpaid = fields.Selection([
    ('yes',"Yes"),
    ('no',"No")],
    string="Can managers override paid leaves to unpaid", required=True)    
carry_frwrdng_leaves = fields.Boolean(string="Carry forwarding of leaves", 
    required=True)  
maximum_accumulation_in_year = fields.Integer(string = "Maximum Accumulation in year", 
    required=True)  
leave_encash_rest_leaves = fields.Selection([
    ('yes',"Yes"),
    ('no',"No")],
    string="Leave Encashment for Rest Leaves", required=True)
employee_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', string="Employee")
holiday_status_id = fields.Many2one("hr.holidays.status", 
    string="Leave Type", required=True) 
department_id = fields.Many2one('hr.department', 
    related='employee_id.department_id', string='Department') 
count_intervening_leaves = fields.Boolean(
    string="Count intervening holidays/weekly offs as leaves", 
    required=True)
count_intervening_leaves_back_date = fields.Boolean(
    string="Count intervening holidays/weekly offs as leaves if applying for back date", 
    required=True)
leaves_probation_period = fields.Boolean(string="Leaves allowed in probation period", 
    required=True)
max_con_leaves_month = fields.Boolean(string="Maximum consecutive leaves per month", 
    required=True)
leave_encashment_cycle = fields.Selection([
    ('annually',"Annually"),
    ('super_annuation',"Super Annuation / Relieving")],
    string="Leave Encashment Cycle", required=True)
description = fields.Text(string="Description")
```

> The code in which i'm not finding any error is :-

```
@api.onchange('employee_id')
def _gender_specification_check(self):
    listed = []
    return_domain_list = []
    res={}
    if self.employee_id.gender == 'male' or self.employee_id.gender == 'female':
        if self.employee_id.gender == 'male':
            s='male'
        else :
            s='female'
        current = self.env['hr_leave_rules.leave_rules'].search([('gender_specific','=',s)])
        for item in current:
            listed.append(item.holiday_status_id.id)
        for item in range(len(listed)-1):
            return_domain_list.append('&')
        for item in listed:
            return_domain_list.append(('id','!=',str(item)))
    else:
        current = self.env['hr_leave_rules.leave_rules'].search([('gender_specific','=',self.employee_id.gender)])
        for item in current:
            listed.append(item.holiday_status_id.id)
        for item in range(len(listed)-1):
            return_domain_list.append('|')
        for item in listed:
            return_domain_list.append(('id','=',str(item)))
            res['domain']={'holiday_status_id':return_domain_list}
    return res
```

**Thanks...**

Comment: I am not getting problem from your question?

Comment: In class HRLeaveRules if i'm allocating a leave for female say, maternity leave is selected for female, then _gender_specification_check should work as if the female employee is selected then in the "leave_type" only the maternity leave should be displayed which i can select and no other leave such as parental leave should not be displayed.

Comment: You are not returning the domain in first part of the if. look at my update on your answer

Comment: sorry i don't know about your correction as i got my answer in the same code without any changes which i have answered.. Thanks..

Comment: I think you need to add a related field with employee_id.gender, then add invisible attribute with condition `'invisible': [('new_field', '!=', 'female')]}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I got my answer with just an Indentation mistake which was**

```
        res['domain']={'holiday_status_id':return_domain_list}
return res
```

*instead of*

```
res['domain']={'holiday_status_id':return_domain_list}
return res
```